# Partial sum of Stirling numbers of first kind

Tags: combinatorics, summation, stirling-numbers

After [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4849890/cardinality-of-a-certain-subset-of-group-s-k-defined-in-connection-with-cycle/4849921?noredirect=1#comment10335317_4849921), that introduced me to Stirling numbers, I have the following question.

For the (signed) [Stirling numbers of first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) $s(k,i)$ and $k>M$, I would like to know **the value** or **a good bound** depending on $M$ and $k$ of
$$ \Delta(k,M):= \sum_{i=0}^M s(k,i).$$

Equivalently, for the unsigned version of the Stirling numbers,
$$ \Delta(k,M)= \sum_{i=0}^M (-1)^{k-i} \biggl[{k \atop i}\biggr].$$

I know that $\Delta(k,k)=0$, from the definition, but other computations seem to require extra knowledge about these numbers.

Comment: There are two variations of the definition of the Stirling numbers of the first kind: Historically the alternating sign version has been favored, but today there is a clear tendency towards the unsigned variant. You might want to point out which version you are referring to. (Personally, I would also modify the question into using the unsigned variant...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_k$ be the set of permutations on $\{1,\dots,k\}$.

> **Theorem:** For all $k\ge 2$, $\Delta(k,m)$ is equal to $(-1)^{k-m}$ times the number of permutations in $S_k$ with exactly $m$ cycles and where $1$ and $2$ are in the same cycle.

*Proof:* Let $S_k^{m}$ be the set of permutations in $S_k$ with at most $m$ cycles. Since a permutation in $S_k$ with $i$ cycles has a sign of $(-1)^{k-i}$, the sum  $\Delta(k,m)$ is equal to the sum of the signs of all of the permutations in $S_k^{m}$. To simplify this summation, we shall partition $S_k^m$ into pairs and singletons, where the two permutations in each pair have opposite signs. These pairs cancel each other out in the summation, so we can sum over the singletons alone.

For each $\pi \in S_k^m$, we will pair $\pi$ with $(1\;\;2)\pi$, except in the case where $(1\;\;2)\pi$ has more than $m$ cycles. Note that $(1\,\,\,2)\pi$ has the opposite sign of $\pi$. This causes all permutations in $S_k^m$ to be paired up, where the only exceptions are the permutations with exactly $m$ cycles, such that $1$ and $2$ are in the same cycle. Since all of the unpaired permutations have a sign of $(-1)^{k-m}$, the entire sum equals $(-1)^{k-m}$ times the number of such permutations.
$\tag*{$\square$}$
As a corollary, we have
$$
\left|\Delta(k,m)\right| \le {k\brack m}
$$
There may be some combinatorial argument which allows you to get a more precise count on the number of permutations with $m$ cycles such that $1$ and $2$ are in the same cycle, and thus to get a better bound than above. However, the above is the best bound I can give.

Comment: I would like to use this, eventually, in a paper, how should I procede?

Comment: Just click the word “cite” that appears below my answer. For some more info, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4259