# Show that $\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^m\binom nm=0$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Show that $$ \sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m \binom{n}{m} = 0$$

I have first difficulty understanding the summation notation: For example
what 
$ \sum_{m=0}^3 (-1)^m \binom{n}{m}$ would mean?
I suppose that it means:
$$ \sum_{m=0}^2 (-1)^m \binom{n}{m}
= (-1)^0 \binom{2}{0}
+ (-1)^1 \binom{2}{1}
+ (-1)^2 \binom{2}{2}
$$

$$ \sum_{m=0}^2 (-1)^m \binom{n}{m}
= + 1
- 2
+ 1 =0
$$

If it is such case, it shows that the value of $(-1)^m$ alternate positive when $m$ is even and negative when $m$ is odd.

Therefore the sum when $m$ is even $+$ the sum when $m$ is odd $= 0$ and we can then factor out the constant $+1$ from the first sum and $-1$ from the second sum and then QED.

Is this approach correct? How to write this using sum notation when $m$ even and when  $m$ is odd?
Is there a better approach?

Much appreciated.

Comment: For your convenience, there is `\binom{n}{k}`.

Comment: This is a rather frequent question here. See [Alternating sum of binomial coefficients: given $n \in \mathbb N$, prove $\sum^n_{k=0}(-1)^k {n \choose k} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/611761) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/611761).

Answer (score 3):

the expansion of $(1+(-1))^n=\sum _0 ^n (-1)^m .(1)^{n-m} {n \choose m}$

Comment: Use ${n\choose m} = {n-1\choose m}+{n-1\choose m-1}$ to see that most of the binomial coefficients cancel. For the rest, use the boundaries ${n\choose 0}= 1={n\choose n}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is Newton's Binomial Series:

$$\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}(-1)^m = \sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}(-1)^m1^{n-m} = (-1 + 1)^n = 0^n = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

We have, $$(a+b)^n=\sum\limits_{m=0}^n {n \choose m}a^{n-m}b^m$$

Now, put $a=1, b=-1$

$\sum\limits_{m=0}^n {n \choose m}(-1)^m=(1-1)^n=0$

Comment: Thx for the input, How do you demonstrate $(a+b)^n=\sum\limits_{m=0}^n {n \choose m}a^{n-m}b^m$?

Comment: That is known as Binomial Expansion.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 1):

There is a combinatorial proof of this fact too. Suppose $n\geq 1$ (otherwise it is trivial). Let $N$ be a set of $n$ elements. Let $S_0=\{A\subseteq N\colon |A|\,\text{even}\}$ and $S_1=\{A\subseteq N\colon |A|\,\text{odd}\}$. The identity in question is equivalent to $|S_0|=|S_1|$. Fix an element $a\in N$. Define the map $\varphi\colon S_0\to S_1$ by
$$
\varphi(A)=
\begin{cases}
A\cup\{a\}&\text{if $a\notin A$}\\
A\setminus\{a\}&\text{if $a\in A$}.
\end{cases}
$$ 
It is easy to see that the map $\varphi$ is a bijection (easy to write down an inverse) and hence $|S_0|=|S_1|$.