# Proof of inverse factorial decomposition $\frac{1}{n!}=\sum\limits^n_{i=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+i}}{(i-1)!(n+1-i)!}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, factorial

Doing research in probability modelling I obtained a decomposition of inverse factorial:

$$\frac{1}{n!}=\sum\limits^n_{i=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+i}}{(i-1)!(n+1-i)!}$$

How can it be proven directly? In what literature can I find it?

P.S. For odd $n$ the equality is trivial because all terms except $\frac{1}{n!}$ vanish. The trick is to prove it for even $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that the formula is equivalent to
$$1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{n+i}\cdot \frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n+1-i)!},$$
i.e.
$$1=(-1)^n\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i}\binom{n}{i-1}.$$

To show this, try using [the fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611761/alternating-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-given-n-in-mathbb-n-prove-sumn) that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}=0$ (which you can show using the binomial theorem).

Comment: Thanks! My vote for your answer is not displayed :(